# Array and File Creation

Tags: java, arrays, filewriter

I am creating a code as part of my assignment by following the following guidelines:

Write a program that will continue to prompt the user for numbers until they enter "Done" to finish, then prompts the user for a file name so that these values can be saved to that file. For example, if the user enters "output.txt", then the program should write the numbers that have been read to "output.txt".

I have gotten near the end, but I cant seem to figure out why its not processing it the way i was expecting it to. For example, this is how it looks when i run it.

```
Please enter number. When complete, please input 'Done': 
1
Please enter number. When complete, please input 'Done': 
7
Please enter number. When complete, please input 'Done': 
10
Please enter number. When complete, please input 'Done': 
Done
File Contents 1710
Please enter file name: Test.txt
fileName: Test.txt
```

I would want the numbers (file contents) to read 1 7 10 and also to create a file which it is not.

Here is my code:

package labs.lab2;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test4 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    String fileContents = "";
    while (true) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter number. When complete, please input 'Done': ");
        String userInput = input.nextLine();
        if ("Done".equalsIgnoreCase(userInput)) {
            break;
        }
        fileContents += userInput;
    }
    System.out.println("File Contents " + fileContents);
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter file name: ");
    String fileName = input2.nextLine();
    System.out.print("fileName: " + fileName);
    //String fileNameFull = fileName + ".txt";
    File file = new File(fileName);
    //File file = new File(fileNameFull);
    file.createNewFile();
//      String fileName + ".txt";
    
//  File file = new File(fileName + ".txt");
//  file.createNewFile();
    
    FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
    myWriter.write(fileContents);
    myWriter.close();
```

Comment: The program does not know where to create your file. You can try "File file = new File("./" + fileName);" to create it at the current directory.

Comment: Just a nitpick, you might want to put something after each number. Perhaps a "\n" or the appropriate system line separator.

Comment: NomadMaker, that sure is brain buster because im not sure where to designate \n in the code.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the absolute path of file that is created using

```
System.out.print("file path: "+file.getAbsolutePath());
```

you place this print statement  after `file.createNewFile();`

if you find that, your file is created at this path

Other simple way it to refresh your project in IDE to find the file created in project

Comment: where would the System.out.print("file path: "+file.getAbsolutePath()); be placed though? after it runs everything?

Comment: updated answer to place print statement after `file.createNewFile();`

Comment: ok, so i was able to find the location. But the test files i created are all blank. This means it is not saving the inputs.

Comment: i  can see the numbers in file created

Comment: Sanjeev, i must be doing something wrong as i still see blank files

Comment: check if code you are running is same as the one you posted here